# I'm getting this error in python project with Tensorflow object_detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, object-detection-api, tfrecord

Create TF records

Code:

```
!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x {IMAGE_PATH + '/train'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/train.record'}

!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x{IMAGE_PATH + '/test'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/test.record'}
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 29, in <module>
From object_detection.utils import dataset_util, label_map_util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 29, in <module>
From object_detection.utils import dataset_util, label_map_util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'
```

I followed Nicholas Renotte video
https://youtu.be/pDXdlXlaCco @ 22:30

I downloaded Tensorflow object_detection models from git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models

And then I ran

```
python -m install pip
```

Comment: Try: pip install tensorflow-object-detection-api

Comment: See this video in depth:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZh_ps8gKgs&t=1417s

Answer (score 0):

After the
`git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models`

you have to run protoc to properly install the API:

```
cd models/research/
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
python -m pip install .
```

after all test it with this script:
`python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py`

Comment: you should give us more infos. Which version of tf do you have?

Comment: Module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'
What to do ? Tensorflow 2.3.1 python 3.7.3

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed relevant dependencies like protoc as below

```
%cd /content/models/research
!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

you need to create environment by,

```
!pip install tf_slim
pwd = os.getcwd()
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += f':{pwd}:{pwd}/slim'
```